# Using PRXMATCH to match strings from another sas dataset

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Need your assistance and guidance. Please see below

```
*rsubmit;proc sql;
connect to teradata(user=&user_id. password=&user_pwd.);
create table mylib.DWH_table as select * from connection to teradata(
select distinct nm from DWH_table
);
quit;*endrsubmit;
*rsubmit;
DATA mylib.out_sas1;
    set mylib.DWH_table;
    if prxmatch ("m/studio/i",nm) > 0;
run;*endrsubmit;
```

So the above code checks for the word "studio" in the column nm and returns the results. However, this is a manual process that needs to be automated. I have another dataset that contains just one column named "KEYWORDS". Some of the sample data I have given below

```
KEYWORDS:
apple
mango
banana
grapes
```

The goal is that SAS should take the word in the column and compare it to the value in the database and create a separate output table.
So for example:

```
*rsubmit;
DATA mylib.out_sas2;
    set mylib.DWH_table;
    if prxmatch ("m/apple/i",nm) > 0;
run;*endrsubmit;


*rsubmit;
DATA mylib.out_sas3;
    set mylib.DWH_table;
    if prxmatch ("m/mango/i",nm) > 0;
run;*endrsubmit;
```

Can this be done in SAS?

Comment: Are you sure you want one table per keyword ?  You might be better served with a binary variable per keyword, and get output with columns `nm`, `apple`, `mango`, `banana`, `grapes` *or* columns `nm`, `match1`, `match2`, `match3`, `match4` where the # correspond to row (and thus key phrase) in KEYWORDS.  Also, depending on the data maybe it would be better to have a categorical form of output recording only the matches `nm`, `keyword`.  A `nm` value would be in the output for each keyword it matches.

Comment: The most effective use of your Teradata resource might be to upload the keywords list and do a pass through join of DWH_table to Keywords using INSTR, POSITION or INDEX. Ex: `on 0 < POSITION (lower(Keywords.Keyword) in lower(DWH_Table.nm))`

Comment: @Richard The keywords are in a SAS dataset (mylib.nouns). The words in this dataset needs to be matched to a DWH table (imported to SAS) containing 26 million rows. The PRXMATCH functions were taking too much time. Do you have any ideas how to implement the INDEX part?

Comment: How many keywords are there (# of rows in mylib.nouns) ?  Do you have an estimate on number of matches ? How wide is the `nm` column ? (i.e. it is VARCHAR(###) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a macro call via a data step using [`CALL EXECUTE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/n1q1527d51eivsn1ob5hnz0yd1hx.htm):

```
%macro subset_data(key);
    %let name_unquoted = %qsysfunc(compress(&key., %str(%")));

    data mylib.out_&name_unquoted.;
        set mylib.DWH_table;
        if prxmatch ("m/"||trim(&key.)||"/i",nm) > 0;
    run;
%mend;

data _null_;
  set mydata;

  call execute('%nrstr(%subset_data("'||KEYWORDS||'"))');
run;
```

Alternatively, instead of `call execute`, create a SAS script file of macro calls, then run with `%include`:

```
data _null_;
  set mydata;

  file "Temp.sas" ;
  put '%subset_data("' KEYWORDS '") ;' ;
run;

%include "Temp.sas";
```

---

But if *keywords* are many (i.e., tens to hundreds to thousands), consider @Richard's comment above to develop an indicator column in a concatenated dataset via a helper, *temp* dataset:

```
%macro subset_data(key);
    *** BUILD temp WITH INDICATOR;
    data temp;
        set mylib.DWH_table;
        if prxmatch ("m/"||trim(&key.)||"/i",nm) > 0;
        keyword = &key.;
    run;

    *** CONCATENATE temp;
    data mylib.subset_data;
        set mylib.subset_data 
            temp;
    run;
%mend;
```

---

**Reproducible Example** *(using [sashelp.class](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_sashelp_sect003.htm) dataset)*

```
proc contents data = sashelp.class; run;

%macro subset_data(key);
    %let name_unquoted = %qsysfunc(compress(&key.,%str(%")));

    data &name_unquoted.;
        set sashelp.class;
        if prxmatch("m/"||trim(&key.)||"/i", Name) > 0;
    run;
%mend;

data keywords;
   input id keyword $;
   datalines;
1     w
2     u
3     y
;

data _null_;
  set keywords;
  call execute('%nrstr(%subset_data("'||keyword||'"))');
run;
```

---

**proc sql** version

```
%macro subset_data(key);
    %let name_unquoted = %qsysfunc(compress(&key., %str(%")));

    proc sql;
        create table &name_unquoted. as
        select * from mylib.DWH_table
        where nm like "%" || trim(&key.) || "%";
        -- where nm index(nm, trim(&key.)) > 0;
    quit;
%mend;
```

**proc sql** *(with SAS## datasets)*

```
data keywords;
    set keywords;
    dname = cat("", "sas", _n_);
run;

%macro subset_data(key, dname);
    %let name_unquoted = %qsysfunc(compress(&dname.,%str(%")));
    proc sql;
        create table &name_unquoted. as
        select * from mylib.DWH_table
        where nm like "%" || trim(&key.) || "%";
        -- where nm index(nm, trim(&key.)) > 0;
    quit;
%mend;

data _null_;
  set keywords;
  call execute('%nrstr(%subset_data("'||keyword||'", "'||dname||'"))');
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your keywords in macro vairables

```
proc sql;
  select count(distinct KEYWORDS)
  into :no_keys
  from mylib.MY_KEYWORDS;

  select distinct KEYWORDS
  into :key_1-key_&no_keys
  from mylib.MY_KEYWORDS;
quit;
```

Now use those macro variables

```
%macro find_keywords;
data 
  %do key_nr = 1 %to &no_keys;
    mylib.out_sas&key_nr (drop = UP_nm)
  %end;
  ;
    set mylib.DWH_table;
    UP_nm : upcase(nm);
    %do key_nr = 1 %to &no_keys;
      keyword = "&key.";
      if prxmatch ("m/&&key_&key_nr/i",UP_nm) > 0 then output out_sas&key_nr;
    %end;
run;
%mend;
%find_keywords;
```

You need to embed this in a macro, because you cannot use `%do` ... `%end;` in "open" code. `&&` resolves to `&`, which makes it a delayed `&`, that is resolved after resolving `&key_nr`.

### Disclaimer: this code is not tested. If you have trouble getting it running, please respond.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to perform an cross join on an *is match* criteria.  The result is one table with one row per name noun match.

Sample data and code:

```
data names;
length name $80;
infile cards length=L;
input name $varying. L;
datalines;
Bob
Bob's Burgers
Angel
Angle iron city
Chad
Chadwicks town council
Dutch
Edward
run;

data nouns;
length noun $10;
infile cards length=L;
input noun $varying. L;
datalines;
chad
own
ward
burger
run;

/*
* might want to pre lowercase the data being matched up
data lower_names;
  set names;
  lower_name = lower(name);
data lower_nouns;
  lower_noun = lower(noun);
run;
*/

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select name, noun 
  from names as NAME 
  cross join nouns as NOUN 
  where index(lowcase(NAME),lowcase(trim(NOUN))) >= 1 /* SAS INDEX() result: 1 or higher means noun is present */
  ;
quit;
```

Regardless of your approach there will be a lot of activity. Suppose there are 100 nouns to be checked against all names, that's 26M names x 100 nouns = 2.6B is match evaluations.  The system that is the most powerful and resource available will usually get you the fastest answer.

Case 1: SAS installation better

- Download names to SAS
- cross join names to nouns in SAS

Case 2: Teradata installation is better

- Upload nouns to Teradata
- cross join names to nouns in Teradata (via passthrough SQL)

Case 1 code:

```
Proc SQL;
  connect to (user=&user_id. password=&user_pwd.);

  * download names;
  create table mylib.DWH_names as
  select * from connection to Teradata (
    select distinct nm from DWH_table
  );

  create table work.NameNounMatches as
  select 
    nm,
    noun
  from 
    mylib.dwh_names as NAMES
  cross join
    mylib.nouns as NOUNS
  where 
    INDEX(lowcase(NAMES.nm),lowcase(trim(NOUNS.noun))) >= 1
  ;
```

Case 2 code:

Teradata temp table -- Upload (`connection=global`) from Tom on https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/SAS-Access-to-Teradata-How-to-create-Temporary-tables-in/td-p/228852

```
libname tdwork teradata username=&username password=&password server=&server 
  connection=global dbmstemp=yes
;
data tdwork.NOUNS_UPLOADED;
   set mylib.nouns;
run;

* cross join in Teradata via passthrough;    
proc sql;
   connect using tdwork;
   create table work.NameNounMatches as
   select * from connection to tdwork 
   ( select Cust.UNIQUE_ID,IP.IP_NAME
     from TABLE_DWH as NAMES_LIST
     cross join NOUNS_UPLOADED as NOUNS_LIST
     where POSITION(NAMES_LIST.nm,NOUNS_LIST.noun) >= 1
   );
quit;
```